# sql alchemy unable to open database file with multiple databases

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy

I created two databases using the following code with python+flask+sqlalchemy

```
from flask import Flask 
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate, MigrateCommand
from flask_script import Manager

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///C:\\Users\\dmac'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_BINDS'] = {
   'user': 'sqlite:///C:\\Users\\dmac\\user.db',
   'stock': 'sqlite:///C:\\Users\\dmac\\price.db'
}
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db, render_as_batch = True)
manager = Manager(app)
manager.add_command('db', MigrateCommand)
if __name__ == '__main__':
   manager.run()
```

I run the following script:

```
python app.py db init--multi 
python app.py migrate
```

I get the following error: sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError:(sqlite3.OperationalError) unable to open database file (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)

I have looked and tried different solutions posted, but I still get the same errors. Any helps would be appreciative. Thanks

Comment: Here are the versions: 
python-3.6, flask-1.0.2, flask-migrate-2.5.3, flask-script-2.0.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're pointing `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI` to a folder instead of a database. So SQLAlchemy tries to open the `dmac` folder as if it were a database which it isn't and fails.

https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/binds/

Comment: I see. Thank you. I will take a look.